# how to enable query log in oracle db 11g - centos 6

Tags: sql, performance, oracle11g, centos6

could you please let me know a way to enable oracle sql db query log in centos 6 environment. in that query log I am expecting to have all the queries which are triggering in sql server. I checked audit log and alert log as well, but none of the log files are not logging quires which are triggering in sql server like in MySql general log.

I am using sql developer as well, if any solution available through sql developer tool, I can accept it.

Thank You,
Best Regards.

Comment: You need to enable the auditing of SELECT statements.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how can I do that, any reference ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need all CRUD operations to be log in to a file or db

Comment: The enable auditing for DELETE, INSERT and UPDATE as well. The details on how to do that are explained [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/part_6.html)

Answer (score 0):

following query was solved the issue and able to log all CRUD operations for a particular user as I expected

```
audit update table, delete table,
  insert table by DB-USER-NAME by access;
```

for further combinations of audit log can be try by referring following link

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_audit_table_command.htm